# Make an iframe in Wordpress open links in the parent window

Tags: wordpress, iframe

Here is my problem, I have an iframe of a wordpress page (with stripped header/fooder/sidebar) with lots of links and I want when the user clicks on the links for them to open on the parent window and not the iframe.

I know I can use:
`<a target="_parent" href="http://url.org">link</a>`
on the links, but since the links point to wordpress posts and the list of posts is updated dynamically, this isn't a very good option. I can't edit them one-by-one to add the target. Plus, it might interfere with the rest of the site's links.

Another option is to use

```
<base target="_parent">
```

on the iframe header but I don't know how to do that.
Suppose I have this code to add the iframe:

```
<iframe class="bg-dark3" style="border: none;" src="https://www.google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Where and how can I add the `<base target="_parent">` line?

Comment: `<base target="_parent">` needs to be added to the page where your links are i.e. your wordpress page. It can be placed in the `<head>` tag

Comment: You mean add it to header.php? Wouldn't that affect the entire website?

Comment: That's correct @Christos Arapidis. You asked where and how it should be placed.

Comment: It's not working because I strip the header. Since the page is of my own wordpress website I remove header/footer/sidebar, as explained in the opening, which also removes the base target code. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your Wordpress site. It's Jquery to open the links in the parent. So please make sure Jquery library is loaded.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  //Get url from anchor
  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  //Open url in parent
  window.parent.parent.window.location = link;
});
```

This will automatically open the links in the parent, you wouldn't need to add `target=_parent` to each link manually.

Comment: I added the following code in my functions.php: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );` then the function: `function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'links.js', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/links.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}`  I checked page source and the js file is loaded but it doesn't seem to be working on the iframe.